# What is the Nalpeiron process?

Tags: windows, process

I can't find any useful information to get what is this process that runs in my computer:
**nalpeiron**

I haven't installed anything tied to that name and google only brings up a licensing company (I certainly don't have any of their product).

Can it be a malware? or is it a legit process which should be there?

I have Windows 7 Professional, fully updated. I tried Spybot, but it didn't find it.
I've heard about this site and this is my first question here, I hope you can help.

Comment: As you can see from the page, Software Copy Protection. Guess you have something which uses this protection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not dangerous at all, it's a licensing component (copy protection) for some software like Adobe Photoshop etc. It may also be installed by games like GTA IV.

Comment: That is very good to hear, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SuperUser!